# Calling Item From List(T) in C#

Tags: c#

How can I call an item that has been added to:

```
List<string> Type = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question, add more details. What exactly you're asking about?

Comment: Is it possible to select an item from the list and set it equal to a variable?

Comment: You mean `Type[0] = foo;`? Yes. You really need to be clearer about what you're asking (and what you've tried already...)

Comment: string myData = Type[i];

Comment: Maybe you want to use LINQ / Lambda?  [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397678.aspx) and [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx).  I -1 this question for lack of basic and reasonable effort to attempt to figure this out (AKA, it takes more time to post here than to search)

Comment: I did try to research and I apologize for not being able to word something correctly. All i'm trying to do is learn. I don't see the need to put down my question. Anyway, I solved my issue and thanks to those who attempted to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use add Method to add string item to list.

```
   Type.Add(item);
```

using for-each you can retrieve the values inside the list

```
foreach(string value in Type)
{
    if(value=="something")
    {
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this is the approve answer based on the information in the question.